# Question about a predictable process - submartingale

Tags: martingales

Question:
Assume that (Xn, Fn) is a submartingale, that
(Hn)n∈N is predictable, and that each Hn is non-negative and
bounded. Show that 
((H · X)n, Fn)

is a submartingale.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any ideas about how to get started with this? For example, what do you know about submartingales that might be useful?